# PHP + GnuPG cannot encrypt file, getting error - no key for encryption set

Tags: php, gnupg

Cannot encrypt file with gnupg, getting error -  no key for encryption set.

```
$currentProjectDir = getcwd();

$privateKey = file_get_contents(
    $currentProjectDir. '/' .$this->_privateKey
);

$publicKey = file_get_contents(
    $currentProjectDir. '/' . $this->_publicKey
);

putenv('GNUPGHOME=' . $currentProjectDir . '/var/keys');
$gpg = new \gnupg();
$gpg->seterrormode(\gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION);
$i1 = $gpg->import($publicKey);
$i2 = $gpg->import($privateKey);
$gpg->addencryptkey($i1['fingerprint'],'qwerty123');
$result = $gpg->encrypt('asdasd');
dd($result);
```

Comment: You're not using your private key `$i2`

Comment: How exactly i should use it? Can you provide an example please?